# Knockout.js "<!-- ko if: --!>" block causing Detach DOM Element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, memory-leaks, knockout-2.0, knockout-mvc

Please find Chtml code segment below:

```html
<span class="GreyText"> 
  <!-- ko if:  vm.Name() == "CHANGE"?true:false -->
    <div style="color: Red; font: bold" data-bind="text : vm.Name">
    </div>
  <!-- /ko-->
</span>
```

I am using Knockout 2.0.3 plugin. Detach Nodes is caused by `Ko_withIfBindingData`. Please guide me on the same.

How to clear Detach Nodes  caused by Ko_withIfBindingData

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: How to clear Detach Nodes  caused by Ko_withIfBindingData

Comment: The way to clear detached nodes is to make sure no code holds a reference to them, preventing the browser from garbage collecting them. Having said that, the code you posted does not seem to be the problem. It's probably caused somewhere else in your code base.

Comment: <!-- ko if:  vm.Name() == "CHANGE"?true:false --> This section of code over using Knockout plugin causing . setknockout-2.3.0.js:59
function (b, c, e) {
     if (e !== q || a.a.f.pa(b, !1) !== q) a.a.f.pa(b, !0)[c] = e }

Comment: I removed  <!-- ko if: block . Please find the below code <span class="GreyText">
<div  data-bind="text : vm.Name"></div>
</span>. And test again with Chrome Developer tool to check if any detach DOM is there or not . But have not found none . So this is clearly says  <!-- ko if: block causing Memory leak Dome detach issue .

Comment: Without the if-block, there will be no nodes that are removed from the DOM and can end up detached. So indeed there will be no detached nodes. This does not necessarily mean that the leak is caused by the same line of code. If some part of your viewmodel references the DOM nodes for example, you could also create the leak there. Memory leaks are not trivial to detect. If you can reproduce this leak in a very simple scenario that does nothing else than the code you just posted, then you must be right. But I doubt you will still have detached nodes if you removed the rest of your code.

Comment: Hans Thanks for your Support . I will try to create a small POC with this If binding and also with out If binding and check if there is any Memory Leak . But For Now I have resolved this issue just replacing <!-- ko if: block  with knockout template binding .

Comment: also why the ? true:false... wouldn't that happen without that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `if` binding will always result in detached nodes. That's because it saves a copy of the element contents as a template for later updates.

If you don't want this behavior, the `visible` binding might work for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I appreciate your effort .